# wifi not working debian 10 buster

Tags: debian, wifi

I have an ASUS laptop with Debian Buster installed and I can only connect to the internet by wire. My WiFi does not work

Output from sudo dmesg | grep 'ath10k\|firmw'

```
# sudo dmesg | grep 'ath10k\|firmw'
[    1.673778] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: failed to load i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (-2)
[    1.673781] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
[    1.673783] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin failed with error -2
[    1.673784] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin. Disabling runtime power management.
[    1.673785] i915 0000:00:02.0: DMC firmware homepage: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/i915
[   12.932696] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   13.595724] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin (-2)
[   13.595847] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin (-2)
[   13.664981] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin (-2)
[   13.665110] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin failed with error -2
[   13.695793] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin (-2)
[   13.695991] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin (-2)
[   13.696084] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin (-2)
[   13.696172] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin (-2)
[   13.696260] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin (-2)
[   13.696336] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Failed to find firmware-N.bin (N between 2 and 6) from ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0: -2
[   13.696420] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[   13.696477] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
[   23.253163] r8169 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw (-2)
[   23.254120] r8169 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw failed with error -2
[   23.254122] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: unable to load firmware patch rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw (-2)
[ 5493.653172] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin (-2)
[ 5493.653180] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin failed with error -2
```

and from "ls -R /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377"

```
ls -R /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377:hw1.0

/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0:
board-2.bin  board.bin  CNSS.TF.1.0  untested  WLAN.TF.2.1

/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/CNSS.TF.1.0:
firmware-5.bin_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1  notice.txt_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1

/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/untested:
firmware-sdio-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.1.1-00061-QCATFSWPZ-1 notice.txt_WLAN.TF.1.1.1-00061-QCATFSWPZ-1.txt

/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/WLAN.TF.2.1:
firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00014-QCARMSWP-1  firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1  notice.txt_WLAN.TF.2.1-00016-QCARMSWP-1
firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00016-QCARMSWP-1  notice.txt_WLAN.TF.2.1-00014-QCARMSWP-1      notice.txt_WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know which ASUS (laptop?) you have and also which wifi hardware it contains. Install (if not already installed) pciutils, by "apt install pciutils", and show the result of the command "lspci | grep -i network"

Comment: lspci |grep -i network
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
Asus R558U

Comment: install the non-free package firmware-atheros and try again to connect (possibly after restart)

Comment: already installed still no luck

Comment: Have you already seen [this](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi)?

Comment: Unable to locate package firmware-iwlwifi

Comment: firmware-iwlwifi is for Intel wifi hardware. it won't work even if you install the package.

Comment: what is the output of "sudo dmesg | grep ath" ?

Comment: sudo dmesg | grep ath
[   12.932696] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   13.595724] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin (-2)
[   13.595847] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin (-2)
[   13.695793] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377

Comment: /hw1.0/firmware-6.bin (-2)
[   13.695991] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin (-2)
[   13.696084] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin (-2)
[   13.696172] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin (-2)
[   13.696260] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin (-2)

Comment: [   13.696336] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Failed to find firmware-N.bin (N between 2 and 6) from ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0: -2
[   13.696420] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[   13.696477] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)

Comment: Hmm... output of "sudo dmesg | grep 'ath10k\|firmw'"?

Comment: please post output for commands not in comment edit your question for that.

Comment: Strange! It seems to me that the firmware for ath10k/QCA9377 is not in it's right place. How about "ls -R /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377" ? And please do not erase the original question, just add to it.

Comment: On my ASUS the directory /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/ contains the driver binaries while you have a lot of other stuff. I suggest, as a first step, that you force a reinstall of firmware-atheros and if the directory /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/ then contains board.bin, board-2.bin, firmware-5.bin and firmware-6.bin, it is OK but if not, we'll try something else. And, yes, my ASUS also runs Debian 10.

Comment: the package was installed from git and in my home directory from where i copied it to the /lib/firmware location

Comment: I would erase those files and reinstall from debian non-free with "apt install firmware-atheros"

Comment: Unable to locate package firmware-atheros

Comment: root@debian:/home/alindsinghal# apt install firmware-atheros

Comment: apt-get update followed by: apt-get install firmware-atheros and if that does not do the trick: edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list so that there is a line "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free" and repeat apt-get update followed by: apt-get install firmware-atheros

Comment: done installed.

Comment: Does the wifi work now?

Comment: yes thankyou very much.

Comment: Very good. Happy to have been able to help.

Answer (score 0):

As your problem seem to be, according to the comments above, that you have downloaded a not completely finished package, I suggest that you erase those files and edit the /etc/apt/sources.list so that there is a line

```
deb deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
```

and issue the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

followed by

```
apt-get install firmware-atheros
```

and, in order to make it work also for updates you may edit the /etc/apt/sources.list so that it contains the lines

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

and, of course update apt by

```
apt-get update
```