# Wi-Fi not working on Debian Buster and Network controller not visible on 'lscpi' command

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

I have been facing this issue where my network card (Intel Wi-Fi module WPEQ-261ACNI along with QCA6174/ath10 as driver) is not detected in `lspci` command.
I have followed this [question thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590567/wifi-not-working-debian-10-buster/727471#727471) but still unable to get network card online.

As I am working with Linux kernel 4.19, I have used backports-4.19.221-1.

- Output from `sudo lspci`:

  ```
  00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
  00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
  00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
  00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
  00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
  00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
  00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
  00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
  00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
  00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
  00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
  01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
  02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
  ```
- Output from `ls -R /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/`:

  ```
  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/:
  hw2.1  hw3.0

  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1:
  board-2.bin  board.bin  firmware-5.bin

  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0:
  board-2.bin  board.bin  firmware-4.bin  firmware-6.bin
  ```

Comment: Does the system have a physical switch for disabling any radio transmitters? Or has the WiFi module been disabled in BIOS settings? Is this system a laptop or a desktop? Some systems (typically laptops) with a dedicated slot for the WiFi module will accept only particular types of WiFi modules that are on a whitelist that is built into the system BIOS; on these systems, if you want to use an unlisted WiFi module, you'll need a modified BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  
No, the system(IPC) does not have a switch, in BIOS there is no such option to enable /disable wireless